# safari browser fails to handle cookie based asp.net sessions

Tags: asp.net, safari

any ideas why my SESSION code works with IE+Firefox+chrome but fails with safari..

page1.aspx has code:

```
   Session("sessioncreated") = Now.Ticks
```

page2.aspx :  problem is here( when user comes to page2:)

```
If Session("sessioncreated") Is Nothing Then
  ' critical error - SAFARI comes here, data is lost

else
  ' all other browsers come here OK
end if
```

how to debug this further?

my web.config has nothing special - I am using just the default values for session handling

Comment: .aspx files are in two folders,  can it cause issue?

Comment: moved aspx files to one folder, but problem continues. Hostname is apps.facebook.com. redirection to new page is done by FLASH.

Comment: Have you got this problem resolved? I am also facing the same kind of issue with my website, it shows white screen with 500 internal server error on Safari only. Please let me know if there is any solution available for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your redirection is causing safari to consider the cookie a third party cookie, and Safari doesn't allow third party cookies inside an IFrame (every facebook app is inside an IFrame nowadays).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have cookies enabled on Safari?
Also, it seems Safari would not accept cookies if you have an underscore on the host name (eg, http://ex_ample/mysite - [source](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/151965)).

Comment: well, my customers report the problem and  I have one MAC and one PC  with safari, both fails.. I guess COOKIES are nowadays enabled by default.  host name is "apps.facebook.com"